# Observable.fromCallable() method inside not getting called

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2, greendao

This is how i'm using the Observable.fromCallable(). In other classes its working fine, but not in some of the classes. Any help would be appreciated.

```java
Observable
.fromCallable(() ->
    getWorkTypeId(tem.getId(), tem.getTypeId())
    .flatMap(oldEntities -> 
        replaceTempAuth(tem.getId(), tem.getTypeId(), 
           getTemes(tem, oldEntities), oldEntities
        )
    )
    .flatMap(deletedEntities -> 
        deleteAllWithId(deletedEntities.stream()
                       .map(TempEntity::getTemId)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList()), tem.getId())
    )
);
```

Here **replaceTempAuth** method and ***deleteAllWithId*** is not getting called.

Comment: You return an `Observable<Something>` which then needs to be subscribed by something. Try `Observable.defer` instead of `fromCallable`.

Comment: Even I tried with defer, but still the result is same. @akarnokd

Comment: Just add .subscribe()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from @kristyWelsh
Added `.subscribe()` works perfectly.